# The order isomorphism theorem without Replacement

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, ordinals, axioms

In $\sf ZF$, there is the following theorem:

> Theorem: For any well-ordered set $\langle A,\prec\rangle$, there is a (unique) order isomorphism $F$ from $\langle\alpha,\in\rangle$ to $\langle A,\prec\rangle$ for some ordinal $\alpha$.
>
> Proof: Define $F$ by transfinite recursion such that $F(\alpha)$ is the $\prec$-smallest element larger than $F[\alpha]$ (the $F$-image of $\alpha$ - note that $\alpha$ is a von Neumann ordinal and hence is equal to the set of all ordinals less than it), terminating when there are no such elements. If the recursion never terminates, this defines a function from $\rm On$ to $A$, a contradiction because $A$ is a set. Thus $F$ has domain some ordinal and the definition of $F$ ensures that $F$ is an order isomorphism.

What is the best equivalent to this theorem if we drop the axiom of replacement here (to get $\sf Z$, Zermelo set theory)? There are two important applications of replacement in the above proof: once in the transfinite recursion theorem and again to ensure that the recursion terminates at an ordinal. It would seem more natural to express the proper class version of this theorem in $\sf Z$, since it is possible to have sets map to proper classes in $\sf Z$:

> Claim: For any well-ordered class $\langle A,\prec\rangle$, there is a (unique) $F$ such that either $F$ is an order isomorphism from $\langle\alpha,\in\rangle$ to $\langle A,\prec\rangle$ for some (set) ordinal $\alpha$, or $F$ is an order isomorphism from $\rm On$ to some initial segment $B$ of $A$.

Is this provable? Is there a stronger theorem that can be stated in this vein? I often see "set-like" being used in statements like these, but I think it wouldn't help here. My prototypical counterexample is to set $A=\omega$ with a well order of order-type $\omega2$ or $\omega3$ within the model $V_{\omega2}$ of $\sf Z$; in this case $F$ will only go as far as the $\omega2$-initial segment of $A$, even though $A$ is set-like (because $A$ is a set).

Comment: Where in the proof of this statement did you get stuck? It's just the usual proof that given two well-ordered classes, one of them is isomorphic to an initial segment of the other.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm probably going to write an answer myself; this is partly a means for me to organize my thoughts before I start formalizing the proof. Actually, I wonder if the claim is missing the assumption of "set-like", because "the obvious proof" that there is a least element greater than $F[\alpha]$ fails since this will be a proper class and well-ordered classes only have minimal elements in sub*sets*.

Comment: So you're saying that in $V_{\omega+\omega}$ the linear order $\ni$ as defined on $\rm Ord\setminus\omega$ is a well-ordering, since every subset is bounded and thus finite, so it is a well-order?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, that's right. (I had a more complicated counterexample in mind but that works too.) I assume we usually want to exclude these from consideration in the order isomorphism theorem?

Comment: This means that you probably want to ever so slightly modify the definition of a well-ordered class.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Am I right in thinking that this peculiarity goes away if you add Replacement? I can't think of any similar examples which aren't foiled by Infinity+Replacement to extract an infinite descending subsequence.

Comment: Under replacement (and infinity) this is the case, since replacement ensures that the decreasing sequence is in fact a set.

Comment: @AsafKaragila ... and countable choice. (?)

Comment: I don't think there's a pretty equivalence between "well-order if and only if linear+no decreasing sequence". Dependent Choice itself is equivalent to "well-founded if and only if no dec. seq.", but the restriction to linear orders causes discomfort. Moreover just countable choice doesn't seem right, or even enough, since you definitely need to have the choices cohere with each other.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Well, in this context one needn't extract a sequence per se but just any subset with no minimum, but thinking about it even with DC it's not necessarily possible since you still have to choose from proper classes. I wonder if there is some permutation model that would turn something like $\omega^*\times\rm On$ into a genuine counterexample of a well-order in ZF with no minimum (by making it impossible to find the set $\omega^*\times\{0\}$).

Comment: I thought we were talking about choice in the context of $\sf ZF$. In absence of replacement or infinity, even with choice, I gave above an example of an order which is unreasonably well-ordered, in every reasonable definition of well-ordered.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I was talking about choice in ZF. But even with DC and ZF, you still can't finish the proof that well-ordered classes have minimal elements without assuming set-like, so I'm looking for a counterexample. (Recall: DC does not allow you to choose elements from a collection of *proper classes*.)

Comment: In $\sf ZF+DC$ a set is well-ordered if and only if every countable subset is well-ordered. If a class is such that every subset is well-ordered, assume that $A$ was a counterexample, i.e. without a minimal element, let $\alpha_0$ be the least ordinal where $A\cap V_{\alpha_0}$ is non-empty, and $\alpha_{n+1}$ is the least where we added an element below all those in $A\cap V_{\alpha_0}$. Let $\alpha=\sup\alpha_n$. Now show that $A\cap V_\alpha$ has a decreasing sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We prove the following version of the Claim:

> Theorem: For any set-like well-ordered class $\langle A,\prec\rangle$, there is a (unique) $F$ such that $F$ is an order isomorphism from $\langle\alpha,\in\rangle$ to $\langle B,\prec\rangle$ for some (class) ordinal $\alpha$ and some initial segment $B$ of $A$, and one of these three holds:
>
> - $B=A$
> - $\alpha=\rm On$
> - $B$ is a proper class
>
> In any of these cases it is clear that $F$ cannot be extended any farther.

We start with the following lemma:

> Lemma: If $B\subseteq A$ is a nonempty subclass of $\langle A,\prec\rangle$, then there is a (unique) $x\in B$ such that $\forall y\in B,x\preceq y$.

Uniqueness follows because $\prec$ is a total order. To show existence, pick some $a\in B$. Since $\prec$ is set-like, $C=\{x\in B:x\prec a\}$ is a set. If it is empty, then $a$ is the desired element; otherwise, by the definition of a well-order there is a minimal element $x$ in $C$. Then for any $y\in B$ if $y\prec x$ then $y\in C$ so $x\preceq y$ since $x$ is minimal in $C$, a contradiction; thus $x\preceq y$.

For the main theorem, we can follow the $\sf ZF$ proof. The problem is that the transfinite recursion theorem (which constructs a function $F$ on $\rm On$ satisfying $F(\alpha)=G(F\restriction \alpha)$) uses Replacement. Nevertheless, one can still establish the following weaker version of the transfinite recursion theorem:

> Given a function $G$, there is a function $F$ such that:
>
> - $F$ is a proper class
> - $F$ is defined on a (class) limit ordinal $\delta$
> - $F\restriction \alpha$ is a set and $F(\alpha)=G(F\restriction \alpha)$ for all $\alpha<\delta$.

In $\sf ZF$ we can use the fact that $F$ is a proper class to prove that its domain is $\rm On$, but in $\sf Z$ this is as strong as we can get. It is still good enough for many purposes: for example if $G:X\to Y$ for some set $Y$, then if $F$ is defined on a set ordinal $\delta$, then $F$ is contained in $\delta\times Y$ which is a set, so we conclude that $F$ is defined on $\rm On$.

In the proof we want to take $F(\alpha)$ to be the minimal element of $\{x\in A:\forall \beta<\alpha,F(\beta)\prec y\}$, and the Lemma ensures that such an element exists. There are two reasons why the recursion will stop: (1) The set is empty for some $\alpha<\delta$, or (2) we have run out of ordinals, i.e. we reach $\delta$ without terminating. In the first case, we have constructed an order isomorphism onto $A$, and in the second case we have constructed an order isomorphism onto some initial segment $B\subseteq A$. Since $F:\delta\to B$, either $\delta$ or $B$ must be a proper class because $F$ is a proper class, and this gives us the three cases at the beginning.